# Return only one row when multiple rows exist

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am working with a database that tracks field trip information for schools.  The query will run on a MS SQL 2005 Server.  There are a few cases when my query will return multiple rows for the same Field Trip.  So, what I want to do is filter my results so that **if more than one row per TripID is returned, display only the row with the MIN StartDateTime.**

I know there's something I can do with the PARTITION and MIN functions but I'm not sure how to go about it.

Here is my code:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT    
        dbo.Trip_TripInformation.RecordID AS TripID,
        dbo.Trip_TripInformation.TripDate,
        Origin.LocationName AS Origin,
        dbo.Trip_TripInformation.OriginDepartureTime AS StartDateTime,
        dbo.Trip_TripInformation.OriginReturnTime AS ReturnDateTime, 
        ISNULL(dbo.Trip_TripInformation.NoOfStudents, 0) AS NumberOfStudents,
        ISNULL(dbo.Trip_TripInformation.NoOfAdults, 0) AS NumberOfAdults,
        ISNULL(dbo.Trip_TripInformation.NoOfStudents, 0) + ISNULL(dbo.Trip_TripInformation.NoOfAdults, 0) AS NumberOfPassengers,
        Destination.LocationName AS Destination,
        dbo.Vehicles.Vehicle,
        Driver.LastName + ', ' + Driver.FirstName AS Driver    
FROM dbo.Trip_TripInformation
LEFT JOIN dbo.Trip_Location AS Origin ON Origin.RecordID = dbo.Trip_TripInformation.OriginLocationID    
LEFT JOIN dbo.Trip_TripDestinations ON dbo.Trip_TripInformation.RecordID = dbo.Trip_TripDestinations.TripID    
LEFT JOIN dbo.Trip_Location AS Destination ON Destination.RecordID = dbo.Trip_TripDestinations.LocationID    
LEFT JOIN dbo.Trip_TripDriverVehicle ON dbo.Trip_TripInformation.RecordID = dbo.Trip_TripDriverVehicle.TripID 
                                    AND dbo.Trip_TripDriverVehicle.DestinationID = dbo.Trip_TripDestinations.RecordID    
LEFT JOIN dbo.Vehicles ON dbo.Vehicles.RecordID = dbo.Trip_TripDriverVehicle.VehicleID    
LEFT JOIN dbo.Employees AS Driver ON dbo.Trip_TripDriverVehicle.DriverID = Driver.RecordID    
ORDER BY TripID
```

Comment: *Duude*... Table aliases would make that more readable.  And the tags are proper -- "microsoft" is too generic

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow : D

Answer (score 3):

`Order by StartDate` and then select the `TOP(1)`

Comment: I don't think this will work.  I may have one field trip with multiple destinations.  That would generate two rows for that TripID (i.e. TripID 1).  This may happen for another trip (let's say TripID = 2) I don't want to just return the top of the entire table, but the top of each TripID as ordered by DestinationArrivalDateTime.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding a row number to your select and selecting your data into a temp table (or use a CTE):

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY dbo.Trip_TripInformation.RecordID 
                    ORDER BY dbo.Trip_TripInformation.OriginDepartureTime asc
                  ) as RowNum
```

Then you can just select from that where RowNum = 1

Answer (score 1):

You need to GROUP them.

Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

You need to join to a derived table which extracts the unique TripId and earliest departure time for each trip:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    ...
FROM dbo.Trip_TripInformation
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT TripID, MIN(OriginDepartureTime) as EarliestDepartureTime 
    FROM Trip_TripInformation 
    GROUP BY TripID
) EarliestTripOnly 
    ON 
        Trip_TripInformation.TripID = EarliestTripOnly.TripId
    AND 
       Trip_TripInformation.OriginDepartureTime 
           = EarliestTripOnly.EarliestDepartureTime
LEFT JOIN dbo.Trip_Location AS Origin ON Origin.RecordID =
    dbo.Trip_TripInformation.OriginLocationID    
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Row_Number function to number each start date within each TripID. In addition, I encapsulated the query into a common-table expression so that I could then fitler on only those Trips where their row numbering was 1 which will represent the earliest date should a trip return multiple rows.

```
With TripInfo As
    (
    Select TInfo.RecordID As TripID
        , TInfo.TripDate
        , Origin.LocationName As Origin
        , TInfo.OriginDepartureTime As StartDateTime
        , TInfo.OriginReturnTime As ReturnDateTime
        , Coalesce( TInfo.NoOfStudents, 0 ) As NumberOfStudents
        , Coalesce( TInfo.NoOfAdults, 0) As NumberOfAdults
        , Coalesce( TInfo.NoOfStudents, 0) + Coalesce(TInfo.NoOfAdults, 0) As NumberOfPassengers
        , Dest.LocationName As Destination
        , V.Vehicle
        , Driver.LastName + ', ' + Driver.FirstName As Driver    
        , Row_Number() Over ( Partition By TInfo.RecordId 
                              Order By TInfo.OriginDepartureTime ) As TripDateRnk
    From dbo.Trip_TripInformation As TInfo
        Left Join dbo.Trip_Location AS Origin 
            On Origin.RecordID = TInfo.OriginLocationID    
        Left Join dbo.Trip_TripDestinations As TDest
            On TInfo.RecordID = TDest.TripID    
        Left Join dbo.Trip_Location AS Destination 
            On Destination.RecordID = TDest.LocationID    
        Left Join dbo.Trip_TripDriverVehicle As TripV
            On TInfo.RecordID = TripV.TripID 
                And TripV.DestinationID = TDest.RecordID    
        Left Join dbo.Vehicles As V
            ON dbo.Vehicles.RecordID = TripV.VehicleID    
        Left Join dbo.Employees AS Driver 
            On dbo.Trip_TripDriverVehicle.DriverID = Driver.RecordID
    )
Select TripID, TripDate, Origin, StartDateTime, ReturnDateTime
    , NumberOfStudents, NumberOfAdults, NumberOfPassengers
    , Destination, Vehicle, Driver
From TripInfo
Where TripDateRank = 1  
Order By TripID
```

A couple of other observations:

1. I notice that every table is using a Left Join. Is it really the case that all the columns in question are nullable? For example, is it really the case that the VehicleID and the DriverID columns in the Trip_TripDriverVehicle table are nullable? You can designate a trip driver vehicle without the vehicle and without a driver?
2. I would recommend using `Coalesce` function instead of the awfully named SQL Server-specific function `IsNull`. They operate pretty much the same but Coalesce is standard and allows for more than two parameters whereas `IsNull` is restricted to two. It won't make any significant difference with respect to your code or performance. It's just a style improvement.

Comment: In this instance `COALESCE` won't make any difference [but it does if the expression being tested is expensive](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/336002/unnecessarily-bad-performance-for-coalesce-subquery).

Comment: @Martin - Although, looking at the link, that could probably be handled by rewriting the query to put the subquery in a derived table and then use Coalesce. Coalesce translated to Case .. When is part of the SQL spec.

Comment: @Martin - Also interesting to note that Connect article is from three years ago. I wonder if it was addressed in R2 or will be addressed in Denali.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM

(SELECT DISTINCT RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TI.RecordID ORDER BY Trip_TripDestinations.DestinationArrivalTime),

    TI.RecordID AS TripID,
    TI.TripDate,
    Origin.LocationName AS Origin,
    TI.OriginDepartureTime AS StartDateTime,
    TI.OriginReturnTime AS ReturnDateTime, 
    ISNULL(TI.NoOfStudents, 0) AS NumberOfStudents,
    ISNULL(TI.NoOfAdults, 0) AS NumberOfAdults,
    ISNULL(TI.NoOfStudents, 0) + ISNULL(TI.NoOfAdults, 0) AS NumberOfPassengers,
    Destination.LocationName AS Destination,
    Trip_TripDestinations.DestinationArrivalTime AS DestinationArrivalDateTime,
    Vehicles.Vehicle,
    Driver.LastName + ', ' + Driver.FirstName AS Driver

FROM    Trip_TripInformation TI

LEFT OUTER JOIN Trip_Location AS Origin ON Origin.RecordID = TI.OriginLocationID

/*More Joins... */

LEFT OUTER JOIN Employees AS Driver ON Trip_TripDriverVehicle.DriverID = Driver.RecordID) Q1

WHERE Q1.RowNum = 1 and (Q1.TripDate BETWEEN '2010/12/13 00:00:00' AND '2010/12/17 00:00:00')
ORDER BY Q1.DestinationArrivalDateTime
```